# Will be there some kind profile aggregation/central page?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, profile-page

Will be there some kind profile aggregation/central page for all StackExchange sites?

Where I can see all my reputation score, stats, badges, **replies** etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stack Exchange Network Profiles**

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/

Answer (score 1):

There already is, assuming all your accounts are associated.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130101?tab=accounts#tab-top

You can get to this page through any of your user profiles, and going to the "accounts" tab on the right side.

Note: this will only show StackExchange 2.0 sites, not the original StackExchange sites. I don't think there will ever be such a page for the latter as they are completely dissociated with the new sites.

---

Re the question edit: Check out [this application](https://stackapps.com/questions/147/stack-bridge-application) over on StackApps.

Comment: Area 51 doesn't show up on any of the other sites so if you create an Area 51 account that will show all your profiles on the other public sites. This will be the most complete list you can see.

Comment: @Chris: Good point. Although I suppose it may be a bug that Area 51 doesn't show up on the Trilogy accounts pages.

Comment: This is hardly the type of aggregation that @MicTech is referring to.  I don't want to go to every site separately to see my "stuff".  I want to see it all in a list.  I might even want to see one page that shows my "Interesting" tags from all SE sites.  That type of aggregation would rock.